# Blale template laravel net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Using Laravel 5, Javascript files aren't working when serving some request(s).

Ex: `http://localhost/loja-virtual/public/category/some_category`, triggers error:

> GET *http://localhost/loja-virtual/public/category/uikit/js/uikit.js*
>    net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Route `http://localhost/loja-virtual/public/category` works normally,
but stops working as I use either :

```
<script src="{{asset('')}}uikit/js/uikit.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="uikit/js/uikit.js"></script>
```

Comment: `http://localhost/loja-virtual/public/category/uikit/js/uikit.js` change to `http://localhost/loja-virtual/public/uikit/js/uikit.js` or check where is your uikit.js file.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are generating these urls ? Laravel offers some great tools to help url creation.

Answer (score 0):

Put your asset's URI inside the `asset()` function:

```
<script src="{{ asset('uikit/uikit.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: yeah yeah, my bad. I had put, i typed wrong here. But i already got it resolved. 
Thank u very much!! :D